# How do I SELECT a number to put into INTERVAL as part of date addition function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, intervals

I have a table which contains a timezone offset, +1, -7, +5 etc.
I have another, joinable, table which contains logging information including a datetime.

I would like to select out the datetime from the second table with the offset added on to it using for example, INTERVAL '1 hours', INTERVAL '-7 hours' etc.

My psuedocode would be something like:

```
SELECT l.status, l.inserted + INTERVAL (coalesce(timezone_offset, '0')||' hours' )  AS inserted FROM log l
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on u.usersid = l.usersid
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies c on c.companiesid = u.companiesid 
WHERE l.usersid=?
```

This doesn't work, but I can't figure out how to make it work in PostgreSQL 8.3.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the result supposed to be? Just a generic timestamp without time zone? Timestamp at UTC (We'd need to define the timezone for the source.)? Local timestamp? Timestamp with time zone?

Comment: The logging is all done in a timezone local to the server, the customer defines their own timezone offset relative to this.  The result just needs to be a timestamp without a timezone.

Comment: I see. You should be all set then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can multiply an INTERVAL by a number.  So if I create an INTERVAL of '1 hours' and multiply that by the stored offset, that will work, yielding:

```
SELECT l.status, l.inserted + (INTERVAL '1 hours' *  coalesce(timezone_offset, '0')) FROM log as l
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on u.usersid = l.usersid
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies c on c.companiesid = u.companiesid 
WHERE l.usersid=?
```

et voila!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use concatenation, so `(l.inserted || ' hours')::INTERVAL` will also work.

Comment: Strangely I did try that (Using cast(), not :: to cast as an INTERVAL) and got an error - but trying it again it seems to work - must have been a mismatch of parentheses - thanks ;)